# Subsequent distances between vectors stored in two data frame

Tags: python, numpy

I have two `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.rand(20).reshape(-1, 2)
B = np.random.rand(8).reshape(-1, 2)
```

where columns can be treated as x and y coordinates in 2-dimensional euclidean space. For each row of `A` I need to calculate minimum distance from all points stored in `B`. My real data is large and I need to care about speed. What's the most efficient way to do that in `numpy`?

Comment: How large is your real data? Give a ball park shape forA and B please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You can do this using numpy broadcasting. The array `R2` has a shape `(A_rows, B_rows)`, i.e. (10, 4). For **very large arrays `A` and `B`**, you may have to apply batch processing. For that purpose use the custom-defined function **`get_distmins()`** as shown below.

```py
# use numpy broadcasting
# R2 => squared distance matrix
R2 = ((A[:,0].reshape(-1,1) - B[:,0].reshape(1,-1))**2 +
      (A[:,1].reshape(-1,1) - B[:,1].reshape(1,-1))**2)
# min distance from all points in B, for each row in A
np.sqrt(R2.min(axis=1))
```

**Output**:

```sh
array([0.18452659, 0.33305075, 0.25056875, 0.37935569, 0.164265  ,
       0.4730478 , 0.23230641, 0.21364414, 0.1050965 , 0.15871064])
```

### Dummy Data

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(seed=42) # for reproducibility

A = np.random.rand(20).reshape(-1, 2)
B = np.random.rand(8).reshape(-1, 2)
```

### How to handle large arrays: `A` and `B`?

We use a `batch_size` to apply batch processing on the arrays.
The custom defined function, `get_distmins()` can do this as follows:

```py
# import numpy as np
# np.random.seed(seed=42)
# A = np.random.rand(20000).reshape(-1, 2)
# B = np.random.rand(8000).reshape(-1, 2)
%%time
distmins, argmins = get_distmins(A, B, batch_size=2000, dtype=np.float32)
```

### Custom Defined Function for Large Arrays `A` and `B`

```py
import numpy as np
# TQDM is used for showing a progress-bar.
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm # --> use only with jupyter-notebook
#from tqdm import tqdm # --> use for both notebook/non-notebook
def get_distmins(A, B, batch_size=None, dtype=np.float64):
    """

    Parameters
    ----------
    A (array): a numpy array of shape (numrows_A, 2)
    B (array): a numpy array of shape (numrows_B, 2)
    batch_size (int or None): Default is None. If None, it auto-selects
                              batch_size = A.shape[0] (numrows_A)
    dtype: Default is np.float64.
           Choosing this could be beneficial in
           managing memory for large A and B (if applicable).

    How to choose a good batch_size?
    If the arrays A and/or B are too large,
    then the calculations may not fit in memory,
    and you will have to use a suitable batch_size
    to process all the data.
     + start with a smaller size of A and B
     + and set batch_size = A.shape[0]
     + check when it can no longer handle
       the data in the memory
     + now choose batch_size such that,
       (A.shape[0] * B.shape[0])_max_allowed
          == (B.shape[0])_true * batch_size

    Example
    -------
    %%time
    distmins, argmins = get_distmins(A, B, batch_size=2000, dtype=np.float32)
    """
    A.astype(dtype, copy=False)
    B.astype(dtype, copy=False)
    if batch_size is None:
        batch_size = A.shape[0]
    argmins = []
    distmins = []
    # use numpy broadcasting
    for start in tqdm(range(0, A.shape[0], batch_size), desc='loop'):
        end = start + batch_size
        #print((start,end))
        R2 = ((A[start:end,0].reshape(-1,1) - B[:,0].reshape(1,-1))**2 +
              (A[start:end,1].reshape(-1,1) - B[:,1].reshape(1,-1))**2)
        argmin = R2.argmin(axis=1)
        distmin = np.sqrt(R2[:, argmin])
        argmins.append(argmin.copy())
        distmins.append((distmin.astype(dtype)).copy())
        #sleep(0.5)
    del R2, argmin, distmin
    # min distance from all points in B, for each row in A
    print('\n>>> done!...')

    return (distmins, argmins)
```

Comment: @Xaume let me know if this worked for you or if you have any other question.